# How to add timezone to datetime in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add timezone offset in utc datetime.Here is my code:

```
 <td>{{amazon.requested_at | date: 'medium' : 'UTC' : '+0430'}}</td>
```

My problem is time is not added to actual time. I want to say that `'+0430'`  is not working

Comment: Do you want to add utc difference to the time or just want to  display just 

2010-10-29 08:40:23 +0500

Answer (score 1):

You need at least **AngularJS 1.3.0** because the `timezone` argument was added from 1.3.0 (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/filter/date) and the code should be:

```
{{amazon.requested_at | date: 'medium' : '+0430'}}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/fvb0qudn/)

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is:

```
<td>{{amazon.requested_at | date: 'medium' : '+0430' : 'UTC'}}</td>
```

Comment: The latest argument `UTC` is useless and it will be skipped, check: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/filter/date